# Blue Snowball Ice usb mic has echo sound

Tags: microphone, audio-recording, echo

I use the Blue Snowball Ice usb mic. I have put mic around 6 - 12 inches from my mouth. I have used [screen cast ometic](https://screencast-o-matic.com) Normalize and Reduce Noice functionalities of that tool. But I can hear a big echo or something like that on my audio. i.e. you need to increase the volume of the audio over 60. Can you tell me how to avoid it? I can use Audacity also.

Audio file: https://vocaroo.com/i/s1Fi2oXT8rlu

Answer (score 1):

You are probably experiencing latency through both the mic and all the processing. This is a recording mic, not so much a 'live' mic that you will want to listen to while you are recording.

Just record the voice directly and don't worry about listening to the audio while you are recording. Audition the audio once you have finished. You are possibly recording a little too close to the mic also.

With some configuration changes you might be able to reduce the latency but you won't remove it completely. So the best solution is not to worry about it. Just don't use headphones when you are recording.